# What will be the output of this? Please explain it also

Tags: c, memory-management, compiler-construction, offset, memory-segmentation

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int a;
printf("%u\n ",&a); 
printf("%p\n ",a); 
printf("%p\n ",&a); 
printf("%fp\n ",&a); 
return 0;
}
```

I have tried this code but I am not able to understand the output

```
4193177020
 (nil)
 0x7ffff9eecdbc
 0.000000p
```

What is semgmented memory address in this and what part is offset?

Comment: Only one of those printf statements is valid; what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: First learn [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Comment: I'm not able to understand 3 of them as well, only one is valid.

Comment: Can you please try executing this. Actually this program is for explaining the segment number and offset address.

Comment: No, this program **does not make any sense**. And FYI, I'm pretty sure that's the [last question you ever asked on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/147015) based on the amount of low quality and heavily-downvoted questions you posted...

Comment: @user2804021: There is absolutely zero information in that program about segment number and offset addresses.

Comment: Format your code, this looks bad.

Comment: @meaning-matters: Agreed, although the lack of indentation is the least of the problems here ;)

Answer (score 5):

Apparently your `a` variable was initialized with `0`.

- `%u` displays an unsigned integer, and you pass the memory address as an argument
- `%p` usually displays the value of a pointer, so in case of 0 it shows it as `(nil)`
- `%p` does the same, but you now pass the address of `a`, which is displayed in hex.
- `%fp` is `%f` (float formatting) and a literal `p`. I'm pretty sure this one causes undefined behavior since printf expects a float and you pass an integer (pointers are long/integer values).

What do we learn from it? **Don't write nonsense code** and **don't pass arguments to printf-style functions unless you have a format string that expects exactly those arguments**.

Comment: Upvoted, but I'd add 'compile with `-Wall` so you are at least warned about your nonsense'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are reading some very old book. Segment and offset combinations were used to address memory in 16 bit applications, they were called "far pointers" as opposed to "local pointers" that contained only an offset (segment was typically taken from the `ds` register for those).

None of this is relevant any more with 32 bit or 64 bit applications. These applications work with a single block of virtual memory that is no longer subdivided into segments. The operating system takes care of mapping parts of the virtual memory to physical memory, this is something that applications no longer need to worry about. All pointers are simply an offset (32 bit or 64 bit for 32 bit or 64 bit applications respectively) inside that virtual memory space - a single number.

As to your `printf` statements, the only one that actually takes the pointer to `a` and prints it as a pointer is `printf("%p\n ",&a)` - the others are invalid as pointed out by the other answer.